# The probability the distance of a point in a square is 2 times the distance from a corner

Tags: probability, area

Let O (0, 0), A (6, 0), B (6, 6), C (0, 6) be the vertices of a square OABC, and let M be the midpoint of OB. Find the probability that a point chosen at random from the square is more than twice as far from O as from M.

I know that vaguely, I must do (area where statement is true) / 36 . I’m struggling to find where it is true. I split the square into 4 quarters and am trying to approach each separately. I’ve concluded that the entire top right is true, bottom left is only true for 0.5pi square units (area of a quarter of a circle with radius root 2 centre of M). Are these right? I don’t know how else to approach this question, and guidance would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The locus of points such that they are equally far from $O$ as from $M$ is the perpendicular bisector of $OM$. However, as Tony K has pointed out, the locus is actually a circle in this problem, so you can't use this fact here.

Comment: @TobyMak: it's not a line, it's a circle. Subbota, the locus of points that are twice as far from $O$ as from $M$ is a circle centre $(4,4)$, radius $2\sqrt 2$. Can you take it from there? (Note that $M$ is _not_ the centre.)

Comment: @TobyMak This question had two parts. The first part asked for the probability that it is equally as far. I used a perpendicular bisector of OM to solve that, same method as you outlined, However this second part is saying let the distance be twice as much of the other distance, and hence it uses circles, I think

Comment: @TonyK Yes thanks! that seems on par with the answer. I just don’t exactly know how or where it comes from

Comment: How or where _what_ comes from?

Comment: I'm guessing it's the equation of the circle.

Comment: How you were able to deduce that “ locus of points that are twice as far from  as from M is centre of (4,4) and radius 2root2” .

Comment: Given two points $X$ and $Y$, and a positive $k\ne 1$, the locus of all points $P$ such that $|PX|=k|PY|$ is a circle. Did you know that? It's not hard to show, using Cartesian coordinates. So now you want to find the circle that (i) goes through $(2,2$) and $(6,6)$ and (ii) is symmetric about the line $y=x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let $O (0, 0), A (6, 0), B (6, 6), C (0, 6)$ be the vertices of a $\square  OABC$, and let $M$ be the midpoint of $OB$. Find the probability that a point chosen at random from the square is more than twice as far from $O$ as from $M$.

Let's find the locus of such points $(h,k)$.
\begin{align*}
2\sqrt{(h-3)^2+(k-3)^2}&=\sqrt{h^2+k^2}\\
4[(h-3)^2+(k-3)^2]&=h^2+k^2\\
\Rightarrow(h-4)^2+(k-4)^2&=(2\sqrt 2)^2
\end{align*}
Hence the locus is a circle with center $(4,4)$ and radius $2\sqrt 2$ passing through the points $(2,2),(2,6),(6,2),(6,6)$.

Can you finish it now?

Don't forget to draw a neat diagram to see what part of the circle is to be considered in the calculation, for the points are to be chosen from inside the square only.

Comment: Thank you, helped a lot!